# 'Database' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Data.Entity.Database'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, simplemembership, ef-postgresql

I have database-first MVC application. The database is postgres with dotconnect data provider. The project works fine without a problem. However when I choose another database in same server, I'm having following error from in InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs class.

```
'Database' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Data.Entity.Database' and 'applicationName.Models.Database'
```

The only deference I can track is the new database is generated from the program called 'dbwrench'. Can anyone explain me what this error is meaning about?

Comment: Both namespaces are in `SCOPE`.  So you need add System.Data.Entity or applicationName.Models. to the name to qualify which of the 2 is implied.

Comment: Can you explain me why does this error not appeared before changing my database?

Comment: I can only guess. Perhaps you have an extra using statement that wasnt there before.  Added by reshaprer or VS.  You needed the reference. It is added. But now database could mean (a) or (b). This is common issue when added types have names that are used in other libraries. eg the Type Database.